# ejabberd configuration - unknown listen option 'timeout' for 'ejabberd_c2s'

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

In Ejabberd 18, the parameter timeout under ejabberd_c2s in configuration seems like not working. When I checked the Log, 
unknown listen option 'timeout' for 'ejabberd_c2s'

Now the problem I am facing is, the client connections are getting closed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#listening-ports right now I see that the *ejabberd_c2s* listener does not support any option named *timeout*.

See:

> ejabberd_c2s: Handles c2s connections.
>
> Options: access, certfile, ciphers, dhfile, protocol_options, max_fsm_queue, max_stanza_size, shaper, starttls, starttls_required, tls, zlib, tls_compression

Where did you read about such an option for that listener?